# How to join 2 tables but keep all values from the original table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to join 2 tables (x for original table, y for other table), but keep all values for the original table even if table y does not contain any data from table x

original table

| purchase_number | revenue |
| --- | --- |
| 78945646 | 5 |
| 45678964 | 10 |
| 3135456 | 11 |
| 789797979 | 12 |
| 1213131 | 13 |
| 487945 | 14 |

table y

| purchase_number | revenue | group_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 78945646 | 5 | 20564 |
| 3135456 | 11 | 20458 |
| 1213131 | 13 | 20421 |
| 487945 | 14 | 20899 |

ideal output

| purchase_number | revenue | group_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 78945646 | 5 | 20564 |
| 45678964 | 10 |  |
| 3135456 | 11 | 20458 |
| 789797979 | 11 |  |
| 1213131 | 13 | 20421 |
| 487945 | 14 | 20899 |

my current code completely ignores the rows where purchase_number does not exist but i would to keep all values from table x

```
select *
from table x
join table y 
on x.purchase_number=y.purchase_number
```

Can someone help me with this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You´ll probably need a left join.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

So it would look like this:

```
select *
from table x
left join table y 
on x.purchase_number=y.purchase_number
```

A full overview on joins can be found here with appropriate visualization
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal by **LEFT JOIN**. I have worked with your data. Check my query in [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/otDYXTJZ2iBtL4viCtmbVU/0).

```
SELECT 
      x.purchase_number, 
      x.revenue, 
      y.group_id
FROM Original_Table x
LEFT JOIN Other_Table y ON x.purchase_number=y.purchase_number
```